# Implement Broadcast feature

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, broadcast, google-home

I am trying to implement Broadcast feature of google in my Voice app.
The device i am using is google home mini. I don't want to use google's broadcast feature, I want to send real time messages through broadcast. How can I achieve this?

I am trying to implement google interpreted mode within two devices.

- My scenario is, I have two devices one located in a hotel room and other at hotel helpdesk.
- The person in a room invokes my action for sending enquiry message to helpdesk
- My action translates the message into the language which is understood by the person sitting at helpdesk and sends the translated message at helpdesk.

Basically what i am trying to do is, request sent from one device and response receive on other device.
So, to let the person know that there is some message for you, i was trying to use broadcast feature.

Comment: Make sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast feature is not available to developers.

You may wish to look into [notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) to send the message to the desk agent and [Media](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) responses to play hold music to the guest while waiting for a response.

Comment: But, how can i send the translated text at the other end, the translation is done within my voice app and then sent as an response.

Comment: Basically, i want to implement google interpreter mode with two devices and two people which are at different location. The in built feature of google is using only one device with 2 people at same location

Comment: You'd want to have some way of delaying a response for some period of time. In the past, Prisoner has recommended using Media Responses as 'hold music' while waiting for a response from your server.

Comment: I want to send a request from one device and receive response on another google device. How can we do that?